# reCAPTCHA issue in website made on webflow

Tags: web, recaptcha, webflow

I am making a website on webflow. I am using a multistep form plugin using tryformly forms. I added reCAPTCHA in forms but the user can click the submit button without checking the reCAPTHCA box. When the user clicks the submit button it shows please wait on the button the form is not submitting as the reCAPTCHA is not ticked. After the reCAPTCHA is ticked user has to press the submit button (which is showing please wait since the first click) again.

I can think of two solutions here:

1. User cannot click the submit button until he/she do not check the reCAPTCHA.
2. A message appears after 5 sec of clicking the submit button that says to click the submit button again.

For the first solution i could not get anything. For the second solution i tried to hide the message line on page load and show it after the submit button is clicked. But webflow does not allow to have a submit button as trigger. Please help me with any solution which works.